# ag-Grid adding css classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ag-grid

I have this simple requirement for my `Angular` application...namely adding a css class when expanding or collapsing a row for the purpose of highlighting said row.  I have tried using `gridOptions.getRowClass` as per the docs https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-styles/#gsc.tab=0 but that appears to have no effect.

My `html` I have added an event handler that will fire a method once the row expands/collapses. My `html` looks as follows:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height:85vh" class="ag-material grid-Holdings" 
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions" 
  [rowData]="rowData"
  ... 
  (rowGroupOpened)="addRowClass($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

...and in my grid.component.ts I have the method which should add/remove a css class:

```
addRowClass(params) {
  this.gridOptions.getRowClass = (params) => {
    if (params.node.expanded) {
      return 'my-css-class';
    }
  }
}
```

One interesting thing is that when I add break points in Chrome dev console I see that it never executes `return 'my-css-class'` but I cannot find any information in the official documentation as to why.  I am really struggling with `ag-Grid` in general, and `Angular` integration with `ag-Grid` in particular.  If this does not work is it better to just do this in vanilla JS somehow... If so, how might I go about this without `ag-Grid` api?

Comment: could you take advantage of the `.ag-row-group-expanded` and `.ag-row-group-contracted` classes

Comment: I see, but how would I apply `.ag-row-group-expanded` to the specific row...say, how would I add a class that bolds the text within the expanded row?

Answer (score 0):

`ag-grid` already toggles some css classes for you: `ag-row-group-expanded` (when expanded) and `ag-row-group-contracted` (when not expanded). You should be able to accomplish your goal by applying the necessary styles to these classes.

Comment: Thanks for this but as you can probably tell from my post I need some help with implementation.  How would I apply this to my example?  Is something like `ag-row-group-expanded` an attribute of gridOptions or rowNode...?

Comment: you'd need something in your CSS, such as `.ag-row-group-expanded { background-color: #F00; }`

Comment: Oh I see, it is not an attribute it is a class!  so in my component inline styles: ... `styles: [
        .ag-row-group-expanded : {color: red}
    ]` Is this what you mean?